# ADFS unable to verify signature of JWT

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2016

I have setup an ADFS server(windows server 2016) in VirtualBox and based on this [Microsoft Flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios), I am trying to get information for the logged in user. I had used both Implicit Flow and Authorization code grant Flow but in both cases I am getting the 'id_token' which I cannot verify the JWT signature. To find the public key I follow the procedure from this [link](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2016/08/oauth2-verifying-azure-ad-jwt-signature.html). But the verification of signature failed on this [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)
Make the call from the browser and postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, my mistake has that in "adfs/discovery/keys" url the value of "x5c" in field the has the certificate and not the public key(I thought it was). To verify the jwt token I get the certificate and extract the public key, then I make the signature verification.